# Debugging System.UnauthorizedAccessException help

Tags: windows, security, debugging

I am trying to debug an application which was not written by myself when an event (adding a user) is fired the application throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Are there an tools that you coulc recommend that would tell me what the application is trying to do?. I do know that is is most probably trying to access active directory is there anything available to trace authentication requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start is by attaching a debugger and breaking on first chance exceptions.  With Visual Studio you can do this by the following

1. File -> Open Project/Solution -> Select your .exe
2. Debug -> Exceptions -> Check thrown for CLR Exceptions
3. Hit F5
4. Do whatever it is that causes the application to crash.

Visual Studio will break when you hit the error and the stack trace on the current exception will show you exactly what is failing.